# flask-sqlalchemy. multilevel join and sort

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

posts table:

```
class Post(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key= True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.String(20),index = True)
    author = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    post = db.Column(db.String(500),index = True)
    comments = db.relationship("Comment",backref = "post_id", lazy = "joined")
```

comments table:

```
class Comment(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "comments"
    id  = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    comment_author_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    id_of_post = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.String(60),index = True)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(500),index = True)
    comment_replies = db.relationship("Reply",backref = "comment_id",lazy = "dynamic")
```

users table:

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60),unique = True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60),index =  True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(60))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    followed = db.relationship("Follow",foreign_keys = [Follow.followed_id],backref = db.backref("follower",lazy = "joined"),lazy = "dynamic")
    follower = db.relationship("Follow",foreign_keys = [Follow.follower_id],backref = db.backref("followed", lazy = "joined"),lazy = "dynamic")
    prof_pic  =db.Column(db.String(40))
    posts = db.relationship("Post",backref = "post_author", lazy = "joined")
    comments = db.relationship("Comment", backref = "comment_author",lazy = "dynamic")
    replies = db.relationship("Reply",backref = "reply_author",lazy = "dynamic")
```

So I'm trying to learn web development. So to try and understand things I decided to go and build my own little social network. just to get the concepts and ideas of relational databases,flask and web dev in general

so far so good.
the users post are in descending order. the latest posts are seen first. people can comment on the posts and it's all well then that's where it breaks.

the posts are ordered in the correct way however the comments arent.
They are commented on the right post but the ordering is based on the `users.id`
so if im `user1` and I comment on `user2's` post my comment will take precedence of users2's post because Im `user1`.

so how do we query this in sqlaclchemy?

```
in pseudocode:

order posts by timestamp in descending order and order comments of post by timestamp in descending order
```

---

## Solved

this issue was solved simply by changing

```
posts = db.relationship("Post",backref = "post_author", lazy = "joined")
```

to

```
posts = db.relationship("Post",backref = "post_author", lazy = "dynamic")
```

Comment: How are you currently doing it? What does the code look like?

Comment: @dirn I updated the question. I solved it now